# Vite: Clear cookies on start up

Tags: vite

We use Vite to run our React platform in a development environment. For internal reasons, the cookies should be deleted every time the Vite development server starts.

Is it possible to do this without writing a custom Vite server? I have been looking into the options for `server` in the vite config but can not seem to find anything. The cookies should only be deleted when the Vite server first spins up, so with the initial request.